# Why my Server Always Change automatically in Folder Permissions?

Tags: linux, webserver, centos, cpanel

i have a centOS server with WHM/cPanel,but i have trouble with my server, sometimes that folder permission change automatically, if after upload image with website folder becomes 755, before upload that folder is 777... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload means you perform an upload with a user to it's home directory and if the user and group of that directory is you only then for /home the umask value is 002 and if you upload a folder and you belong to a common group which is used by other users too the umask value for /home becomes to 022 so it makes the dir/folder permission as 755. So which user you are trying to upload that matters, upload with a user & group which are equal say janitra is the user and group is also janitra.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Thanks for your answer, heres my owner directories on my server

drwxr-x---  57 user87127 nobody       4096 Sep 20 17:41 public_html/

look at my user group, it's nobody, how about that? Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes i.e correct for nobody it belongs to others group so permission is 750 in your case, but owner user87127 has full permission being the owner

Comment: If you are satisfied with your answer pls upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, heres my owner directories on my server

drwxr-x---  57 user87127 nobody  4096 Sep 20 17:41 public_html/

look at my user group, it's nobody, how about that? Is that the problem?